# Check if array contains more than one element

Tags: php, arrays

There is 4-5 different emails there appears several times in the array. I want to know how many times does 4 emails appears.

```
$member_sql = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT email FROM exp_members");

$member_result = $member_sql->result_array();
if(isset($member_result[0]))
{
$member_result = $member_result[0];
```

My error is in the if statement below. My if statement does not show anything. probably because it is incorrectly written. Can you guys help with this statement, what to write here.

```
if(count(array_keys($member_result, $member_result['email']))> 1)
{
echo "Do something";

}
```

Comment: you are missing a final ")".

Comment: I just updated the version. The same problem happens.

Comment: Is member result not a single row??

Comment: print_r($member_result) and let see

Comment: @AkamOmer: Line print_r($member_result) works, and i already knew that. Know i want to know how to get the amount of different emails appears in the array.

Comment: if count not working, then, your array is different in structure, if you can post print_r($member_result) then we can decide what is the error

Comment: Array ( [email] => test11@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test22@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test22@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test666@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test11@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test9999@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test9999@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test521211@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test521211@hotmail.com ) Array ( [email] => test521211@hotmail.com )

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for a **mysql_num_rows** ?

Comment: This should be more efficient too

Comment: do not use mysql_* functions, use mysqli_result::$num_rows http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php